# AngularJs: Why we always keep form submit button disabled?

Tags: html, forms, validation, angular

I have worked on AngularJs and now working on Angular2. Whenever I searched for `form validation in angular` I always found the `submit` button like below:

In AnglarJs

```
<input type="submit"
  ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
  myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
```

In Angular2

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
             [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

But I wanted the submit button should be enable and whenver user click on that we prompt the error below the text fields. There is no exact solution mentioned for this purpose.

I found some of that some of the users directly clicks on submit button and they wanted to fill only required fileds.

This is my observation only may be some of you also experienced the same while development.

For AngularJs 1 I am using `custom-submit` directive from here

https://gist.github.com/maikeldaloo/5133963

So please suggest me any solution to provide `custom-submit` in angular2 also.

---- Sample Login Form (Angular2) ---

```html
<form class="ui large form" (ngSubmit)="onUserLogin(loginForm.form.valid)" #loginForm="ngForm" method="post" novalidate> 
            <sm-loader [complete]="!formSubmited" class="inverted" text="Loading..."></sm-loader>
            <div class="field">      
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="login.email" #email="ngModel" required />
              <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine" class="error text-left">
                Email is required
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">      
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="login.password" #password="ngModel" required />
              <div [hidden]="password.valid || password.pristine" class="error text-left">
                Password is required
              </div>
            </div>            
            <button class="fluid yellow large ui button" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
```

Please check what `custom-submit` directive are doing. Please give me answers the based on that. I know I can check the form valid status on controller level, but why this way I can say only form is not valid, I can not say which field is empty (we can also check this which field is valid, but don't know how to enable the error divs from controllers)

Please refer this...
https://gist.github.com/maikeldaloo/5133963

Thanks,

Comment: What's the problem with just not disabling the button?

Comment: Nothing, but it should prompt the error message below the text fields or other fields whenever I click on submit button.

Comment: If its angular 1 you could use `ng-messages` directive, if you are using A2 then add span/div and show/hide validation based on form field validity

Comment: @PankajParkar Just added my login form HTML code. I am using the `div` for showing error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a state and show/hide the errors depending on the state:

```
onSubmit() {
  if(hasErrors()) {
    this.hasErrors = true;
    return false; // preventDefault
  }
  this.postData(); // process submit event
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="hasError">
  ... error info here
</div>
```

Comment: This could be one of the solution but how do you handle if there are multiple fields in the form and you have to show each error on below the fields. Please check my login HTML code.

Comment: You can have such a `<div *ngIf="hasError">` for every input. You can also build a custom input component, that contains the input and the part that displays the error.

Comment: Can you please update your answer based on my HTML form.

Answer (score -1):

This way we actually validate whether you have entered the correct values or not. If any of the value fails then submit button gets disabled otherwise enabled.

For ex: E-mail : If email id doesn't have @ and ., then it will be considered as dirty, which wouldn't lead to enable the submit button.

Edited:

To display the message you can do one thing:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="done(heroForm.form.valid)" />
```

And in controller you can do this way.

```
$scope.done = function(valid){
  if(valid) {
   // Form content is valid, process it
  } else {
  // show error and do nothing.
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that should be there (it should check for validation whenever you enter something on text fields) but I needed to show the error message before hand to the users whenever they click on submit.

Comment: Edited the answer :)